# What factors must one consider choosing an NN structure?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-networks, neural-computing

Suppose we have a classification problem and we wish to solve the problem by Neural Network. What factors must one consider choosing an NN structure? e.g Feed Forward, Recurrent and other available structures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a list of parameters you should take into consideration (to name some):

1. The learning algorithm (gradient descent is the most explained of them)
2. The number of layers (3,4 layers is usually enough - input, 1 or 2 hidden, output). The output layer depends on your output (e.g., if you want to classify yes/no then your output layer consists of two nodes). The same applies for input layer. However, you may consider the case of using only a subset of the input for the learning. For instance, you may think that your problem is affected by $k$ variable. However, if you take $k'$ of them then you may get better results.
3. Number of nodes in the hidden layers (you select that by trial and error)
4. Number of training iterations (not too much to avoid over-fitting)
5. Size of training/testing data (there are some known rules like the 80:20 for example)
6. The type of the function used at the nodes (neurons) (e.g. $f(x) = 1/(1+e^x)$ or $f(x) = tanh(x)$), usually the first is sufficient.
7. An important issue is the pre-processing and post-processing of data (this is common in all pattern recognition techniques). You may for instance convert your data by applying a certain function $f$ and then run your experiments.

**Note**: given the many parameters you need to deal with, it is a good approach to use a search algorithm to select the best parameters for you. It is better be a heuristic search algorithm (e.g. genetic algorithm) if you had very large number of parameters set you will deal with (which is usually the case).

**Note**: use the Matlab NN library or Weka (open source). They would have all these parameters for you.  In fact, Weka has many other learning algorithms.

**Note**: Perhaps, you may want to use other algorithms then. If this is case, try support vector machines. There was a historical battle between these two algorithms (in the 1990's). SVM won it ! (I am not being very scientific here).

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. The problem is, I have a classification problem and no information about an appropriate NN that I must use, i.e about number of layers and nodes and such things. How should I know that, for example, how many hidden layers would be good for my problem?

Comment: I already said that. trial and error, or you may use a search algorithm.